# Powershell foreach - variable not work

Tags: powershell, foreach

My miniScript not work... why?:

```
Get-VM | select name | ? { $_.Name -like "*411D*" } -OutVariable VmWareName
$VmWareName |foreach {
     Restore-VMSnapshot -Name * -VMName $_ -Confirm:$false
}
```

Sorry, can not English

Comment: What about it isn't working? Are you getting an error? Is the `$VmWareName` variable not set? Is the loop not working?

Comment: Loop Working. If i make only "$_" the output is perfect. Here the Error:
<code>
"0" konnte nicht mit "        " verglichen werden. Fehler: "Der Wert "System.Object[]" vom Typ "System.Object[]" kann nicht in den Typ "System.Int32" 
konvertiert werden."
In Zeile:5 Zeichen:12
+ for ($i=0; $i -lt $VmWareName.Length; $i++)
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure
 
</code>

Comment: The [`Restore-VMSnapshot` documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848480.aspx) makes it look like you can't use `*` with `-Name`. Does fixing that make it work? The documentation also has an example for how to restore the most recent snapshot.

Comment: Restore-VMSnapshot -Name * -VMName 411D-SRV -Confirm:$false - thats work. The Problem is the $_ in foreach...

Comment: In question you use `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, but error, that you post in comments, show `for` loop.

Comment: @PetSerAl points out a good point. That error seems to come from *different* code then what you have in the post. What error does the *exact* code in the post trigger?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you output an object with one property: Name

What you want is a string, with the value of the Name property. You have 2 options. Either refer to the Name property of the object within your loop like this:

```
     Restore-VMSnapshot -Name * -VMName $_.Name -Confirm:$false
```

Or expand the Name property when you save it to your variable like this:

```
Get-VM | select -Expandproperty name | ? { $_ -like "*411D*" } -OutVariable VmWareName
```

Comment: Thx, that script is better (the output). But it´s not work. Powershell say the Parameter "VmName" can not be checked. The argument is null or empty

Comment: That works: Get-VM | select -Expandproperty name | ? { $_ -like "*411D*" } -OutVariable VmWareName | %{ Restore-VMSnapshot -Name * -VMName $_ -Confirm:$false}